# could not fetch json object using jsonpath

Tags: json, jsonpath, jayway

I've a requirement to fetch value from json using jayway jsonpath.

Json structure looks like below

```
[
  {
    "type": "a",
    "values": [
      {
        "name": "a",
        "value": [1,2,3]
      },
      {
        "name": "b",
        "value": [3,4,5]
      },
      {
        "name": "c",
        "value": [6,7,8]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

my requirement is in the values array if the `name` value is `a` and value array contains value `1`, then I need to fetch `value` array where `name` is `b`.

I have written jsonPath expression like below

```
$..values[?(@.name == 'a')]
```

where it is returning only

```
{
  "name": "a",
  "value": [1,2,3]
}
```

could someone help me in writing jsonpath expression please , Thanks in advance.

expected output

```
[3,4,5]
```

tried with

```
$..[?(@.values[?(@.name== 'a' && @.value CONTAINS 1)])]
```

then it is matching every object present in root array.

Comment: Can you please include the expected output in JSON format?

Comment: JSON Path isn't going to do this for you because it doesn't have conditionals that operate iteratively. You need a programmed solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Jayway JSONPATH you might get lucky with below jsonpath

```
$..[?(@.values[?(@.name=='a')].value[*] contains 1 )].values[?(@.name=='b')].value[*]
```